# hook_node_view_alter not working

Tags: nodes, hooks, 9

I'm hoping to finally find some solutions here. I'm new to custom module development in Drupal and I'm trying to learn the basics. What I'm trying to do is use hook_node_view_alter, however even at the simplest step (showing a status message) it does not work.

My module (test_module) is installed and enabled on the site. Currently the custom module has only two files: test_module.info.yml and test_module.module

Code from test_module.info.yml file

```
name: test_module
type: module
description: Test module
core: '8.x'
```

Code from test_module.module file

```
<?php
/*
* Implementation of hook_node_view_alter
*/

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\NodeInterface;


function test_content_node_view_alter(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Hello!'));
}

?>
```

It doesn't show the message when I'm opening a node (/node/1) at my Drupal site. As I understand it, it should show the message for any existing node when it is viewed. I've cleared the cache, nothing's changed.

---

Update

- changed test_content_node_view_alter() to test_module_node_view_alter()
- adjusted the code to [coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards)
- removed the php closing tag

My code in test_module.module looks like this right now:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Implementation of hook_node_view_alter();
 */

use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\NodeInterface;

function test_module_node_view_alter(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Hello!'));
}
```

I've cleared all cache and now the website gets this error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: Naming of your hook looks a little off. The format is 'MODULE_node_view_alter' and your module name is 'test_module' Give 'test_module_node_view_alter' a try.

Comment: I've changed the name, but the module is still not working. Updated original post with new code.

Comment: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." When developing, *always* enable verbose error output, so you can see what's wrong.

Comment: I missed that it was your first post when I first looked at this. So WELCOME! And great follow up with edits to the original question and supplying an the final full answer to help others later.

Answer (score 2):

After researching more examples out there in the Web, I've finally managed to make this work, however I'm still not sure why it was not working before...

Working code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Implementation of hook_entity_view_alter();
 */

function test_module_entity_view_alter($entity, $type, $view_mode) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Hello world!'));
}
```

Moving on to further modifications. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need replace

```
function test_content_node_view_alter(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Hello!'));
}
```

to

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_entity_view().
 */
  function test_module_entity_view(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Hello!'));
  }
```

`hook_node_view()` it's invoked has just changed. As you mentioned, it's now handled by [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view/8.2.x). or [hook_entity_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/8.2.x)

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.6.x is still an existing hook, so `hook_node_view_alter()` should work, if `hook` is replaced correctly.

Comment: you change `test_content_node_view_alter` to `test_module_node_view_alter`

Comment: You should edit your code to follow Drupal's [coding standards](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards).

Comment: I've updated the post. As @leymannx suggested, I've also reviewed coding standards and adjusted the code... Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

This DOES still work in D8 and D9 :)

```
function MYMODULE_node_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'company') {
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('Hello!!!'));
  }
}
```